# Woocommerce rest api integrate with laravel error

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5.6, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using `woocommerce rest api 2.0` and `php 7.1` and `laravel 5.6+`. I try to install Laravel 5 wrapper for the Woocommerce REST API but it throws an error.

This is the error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for pixelpeter/laravel5-woocommerce-api-client 3.0 -> satisfiable by pixelpeter/laravel5-woocommerce-api-client[v3.0.0].
    - pixelpeter/laravel5-woocommerce-api-client v3.0.0 requires automattic/woocommerce 1.3.* -> satisfiable by automattic/woocommerce[1.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Is there any possible solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is require [automattic/woocommerce](https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce) lib, so you should install this library first.

```
composer require automattic/woocommerce
```